# How to open a link in android?

Tags: android, url

Hi im writing this application where i need to open a URL. How can it be done in android? is something like opening a HttPClient or something??

Comment: do u want to send data to the url? or go to that particular url?

Comment: Do you need to open a URL in a browser/WebView? Theres plenty of links around here that should help you.

Comment: You need to be more specific. What do you mean by "open a URL"? What have you tried already?

Comment: Hi sorry! @Anurag I just need to recieve data from the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay so basically i m assuming that u send some parameters to a particular URL where they are processed and result is sent back. in that case the best way is to use DefaultHttpClient to post data to URL in json format. [this](http://fahmirahman.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/connection-between-php-server-and-android-client-using-http-and-json/) example here is something you should look at.

Answer (score 0):

A example about open a url from link textview

```
private void setAsLink(TextView view, String url){
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(url);
    Linkify.addLinks(view, pattern, "http://");
    view.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href='http://"+url+"'>http://"+url+"</a>"));
}
```